# Active Google Cloud Scheduler not triggerig PubSub Event

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cron, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

My google cloud scheduler just stopped working randomly.
It has not triggered in the last few hours and there are no logs in the scheduler.

I tried setting up a new one but that one does not trigger either. Status "Has not run yet".
I can't even run it manually with the "RUN NOW" button.

What are some possible points of failure?

I updated the cloud function it is supposed to trigger recently, but the function works just fine when started manually.

I spellchecked the topic but there seems to be no issue there neiter.

Comment: I understand that this question is already a month ago, but it is possible that this is due to March 24 incident with Cloud Tasks: https://status.cloud.google.com/incidents/6wryTfuzefvshsv4Pdkn

Comment: If you were able to resolve this issue, how did you do it? I am having the same problem at the moment.